# Change Wordpress "Register" link

Tags: wordpress

I am using a plugin with custom forms to handle user registration in Wordpress.

Therefore, I want the "Register" link on e.g. wp-login.php to point to my custom registration page, instead of `wp.login.php?action=register`. What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has great api/hooks documentation on how to customise the login page and can easily be found on google (first result)
the [full documentation is here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)

the `wp_register` is where you'll need to look to edit the `login_footer` section of the login form.

The link for registration goes to `wp-login.php?action=register`, you could always add a htaccess redirect to another (your) page if you dont fancy going down the wordpress api route.

Comment: Is there any plugins for this, i don't want to touch the code may be it will effect the upgrades etc.

Comment: it wont effect any upgrade. you make the changes in `functions.php`, not the word press core code (the `functions.php` is inside your theme)